# How to lay a Density Distribution line over a Histogram (from binned Data) in vega-lite

Tags: vega-lite, vega

In Vega-lite I have created a Histogram with binned Data, is it possible to lay a density line over it. Getting data from elastic database index.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v2.6.json",
  "data": {
    "url" : {
        "index": "artefact_data",
        "body": {
          "size":10000,
          "_source": ["bin_start", "bin_end", "count"]        
        }
      }  
      "format": {"property": "hits.hits"},
  },
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "_source.bin_start",
      "bin": {"binned": true, "step": 2}
    },
    "x2": {"field": "_source.bin_end"},
    "y": {
      "field": "_source.count",
      "type": "quantitative"    
    },
    "color": {"value": "green"},
    "opacity": {"value": 0.6},
    "tooltip": [
      {"field": "_source.count", "type": "quantitative", "title":"Count"}
    ]
  }
}
```

Plot looks line
[image]

1. Can we plot a density line on the histogram
2. X-axis showing value only at the start, other values are not showing or hiding, How to display the axis values (even at 45deg)

like
[image]
Sample data will look like (https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/bar_binned_data.html)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the density line, you can use `interpolate` config in line `mark` and check different options. For example in the below sample I have applied `natural` interpolate. Also to show all the label points, first you can try providing `labelAngle` in x-axis's `axis` config if it works to show your labels properly or you can enable the label overlapping by providing `labelOverlap` to `false`. Below is the sample config or refer [editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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).

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"bin_start": 8, "bin_end": 10, "count": 7},
      {"bin_start": 10, "bin_end": 12, "count": 29},
      {"bin_start": 12, "bin_end": 14, "count": 71},
      {"bin_start": 14, "bin_end": 16, "count": 127},
      {"bin_start": 16, "bin_end": 18, "count": 194},
      {"bin_start": 18, "bin_end": 20, "count": 54},
      {"bin_start": 20, "bin_end": 22, "count": 47},
      {"bin_start": 22, "bin_end": 24, "count": 35},
      {"bin_start": 24, "bin_end": 26, "count": 27}
    ]
  },
  "width": 600,
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": "bar",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "bin_start", "bin": {"binned": true, "step": 2}},
        "x2": {"field": "bin_end"},
        "y": {"field": "count", "type": "quantitative"}
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "line", "stroke": "green", "interpolate": "natural"},
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "bin_start",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "bin": {"binned": true, "step": 2},
          "axis": {"labelAngle": 45, "labelOverlap": true}
        },
        "x2": {"field": "bin_end"},
        "y": {"field": "count", "type": "quantitative"}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, This is perfect